# Base64 to video conversion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, base64

I am trying to convert a base64 string into a video file for use in a gem.

How do you take the base string and reformat it to what it was before it came through http.

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.5/libdoc/base64/rdoc/Base64.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `Base64.decode` and write directly the results to a file.

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.5/libdoc/base64/rdoc/Base64.html

Comment: trying to recontruct a video coming from an api

Comment: Then you should decode like I say in my answer and write it to a file. Note that I don't know how the file is encoded (i.e. which video format it is) so your media player should be able to get the correct codec.